# Can multiple people edit the same excel file using Microsoft Graph Excel APIs

Tags: excel, azure-active-directory, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to have a solution where a single administrator account would make calls on behalf of the signed in users on a web app to perform CRUD operation on a single shared excel file stored in the administrators OneDrive.

This is how the flow will look like.

- User signs into web app and performs a operation.
- The web app on behalf of the user gets access_token from Azure Active Directory and then performs the operation on the excel file stored in OneDrive based on the Microsoft Graph API.

Now suppose there are multiple users logged in to the web app and make requests. How will the Graph API respond to this scenario?

Does Microsoft Graph API support concurrent requests to edit.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Graph throttling limits the number of concurrent calls to a service to prevent overuse of resources.

When a throttling threshold is exceeded, Microsoft Graph limits any further requests from that client for a period of time. When throttling occurs, Microsoft Graph returns HTTP status code 429 (Too many requests), and the requests fail.

For more details, refer to  [Microsoft Graph throttling guidance](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/throttling).

Comment: although this helps i'm thinking specifically about how excel will respond to multiple api calls and multiple people editing the same sheet and so on

Comment: @thebenman May be this is about the architecture of the MS graph, could not find it.